# rename multiple files in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, rename, sh

rename multiple files...in shell

I have 3 files in a dir

```
abc.tar.gz
abc2.tar.gz
abc3.tar.gz
```

using this command :

```
rename abc abc.part abc*.tar.gz
```

it converts them into

```
abc.part.tar.gz
abc.part2.tar.gz
abc.part3.tar.gz
```

after it I added 3 more files in it..

```
abc.tar.gz
abc2.tar.gz
abc3.tar.gz
```

and when I fire rename abc abc.part abc*.tar.gz

it will rename all the 6 files so final output is

```
abc.part.tar.gz
abc.part.part2.tar.gz
abc.part.part3.tar.gz
abc.part.part.tar.gz
abc.part2.tar.gz
abc.part3.tar.gz
```

I just want to prevent multiple rename... what should my `rename` command?

means my final output should be below,no matter how much time I fire rename command.
here the number of files are `DYNAMIC` ..it could be 3,4...or whatever... so cannot add statically 3 or some number !!

```
abc.part.tar.gz
abc.part2.tar.gz
abc.part3.tar.gz
```

Comment: This does not sound like a bash/sh question.

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Answer (score 1):

As the final argument to rename, use:

```
abc{,2,3}.tar.gz
```

Comment: and what I suppose to do if more numbers are there ? can you tell me some dynamic?

Comment: You an also use `abc{,[23]}.tar.gz` or `abc{,[0-9]}{,[0-9]}.tar.gz`

Answer (score 0):

Create the following "ChangeExt" script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then 
   echo "$0 NEWEXT FILENAME.." 
   exit 1
fi

$newext=$1
shift

for a in $* 
do
  mv $a "`basename $a`.$newext"
  echo "$a to `basename $a`.$newext"
done
```